# Mono.count block indefinitely

Tags: java, project-reactor

I ran this:

```
Mono<Void> mono = Mono.empty();

System.out.println("mono.block: " + mono.block());
```

and it produces:

```
mono.block: null
```

as expected. In other words, calling `block` will return immediately if the `Mono` already completed.

Another example, resembling the real-world scenario. I have a source flux, e.g.:

```
Flux<Integer> ints = Flux.range(0, 2);
```

I make a connectable flux that I will use to allow multiple subscribers:

```
ConnectableFlux<Integer> publish = ints.publish();
```

For this example, let's say there's a single real-work subscriber:

```
publish
   .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("publish completed"))
   .subscribe();
```

and another subscriber that just produces the element count:

```
Mono<Long> countMono = publish
   .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("countMono completed"))
   .count();

countMono.subscribe();
```

I connect the connectable flux and print the element count:

```
publish.connect();

System.out.println("block");

long count = countMono.block();

System.out.println("count: " + count);
```

This prints:

```
publish completed
countMono completed
block
```

In other words, both subscribers subscribe successfully and complete, but then `countMono.block()` blocks indefinitely.

Why is that and how do I make this work? My end goal is to get the count of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this to work by using `autoConnect` or `refCount` instead of manually calling `connect()`.

For example:

```java
        Flux<Integer> ints = Flux.range(0, 2);
        Flux<Integer> publish = ints.publish()
                .autoConnect(2);  // new 
        publish
                .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("publish completed"))
                .subscribe();
        Mono<Long> countMono = publish
                .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("countMono completed"))
                .count();
        // countMono.subscribe();
        long count = countMono.block();
        System.out.println("count: " + count);
```

#### Why does your example not work?

Here is what I think is happening in your example... but this is based on my limited knowledge, and I'm not 100% sure it is correct.

1. `.publish()` turns the upstream source into a hot stream
2. You then subscribe twice (but these don't start the flow yet, since the connectable flux is not connected to the upstream yet)
3. `.connect()` subscribes to the upstream, and starts the flow
4. The upstream, and the two subscriptions that were registered before `connect()` complete (since this is all happening in the main thread)
5. At this point the ConnectableFlux is no longer connected to the upstream, because the upstream has completed  (The reactor docs are light on details on what happens to a ConnectableFlux when new subscriptions arrive after the upstream source completes, so this is what I'm not 100% certain about.)
6. `block()` creates a *new* subscription.
7. But since the ConnectableFlux is no longer connected, no data is flowing
8. If you were to call `connect()` again (from another thread, since the main thread is blocked), data would flow again, and the `block()` would complete.  However, this would be a *new* sequence (not the original sequence that completed in step 4)

#### Why does my example work?

Only two subscriptions are created (instead of 3 in your example), one from a `.subscribe()` call, and one from `.block()`.  The ConnectableFlux auto connects after 2 subscriptions, and therefore the `block()` subscription completes.  Both subscriptions share the same upstream sequence.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. How would I do this if `Mono` is down the chain, i.e. not a direct subscriber to `ConnectableFlux`? Or to put it another way - is there a way to get the latest result from a `Mono` in a blocking manner?

Comment: I don't quite understand exactly what you want, but...  To get values emitted from previous subscriptions, you could use `.cache` (so that future subscribers see the same value for a period of time). Or you could save emitted values somewhere outside of the stream (from `doOnNext`), and then look up the value from the saved location.

Comment: Above I have `Mono<Long> countMono = publish.count()`. Say that I have `Flux<Integer> publish2 = publish.flatMap(e -> whatever)` and then `Mono<Long> countMono = publish2.count()`. I.e. there's an intermediate stream (or more than one) between `publish` and `countMono`. The above would make `publish2` auto-subscribe, but it might finish before `countMono.block()` is called, thus running into the same problem, right? `cache` would cache indefinitely though, correct? Might be a problem for long-running jobs.